# Magento : 7405,8788 pactch

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788, supee-7405

I installed 7405 and 8788 patches to my project.Patches applied succesfully in applied.path.list file but in mage report it shows "not installed".Why
Any idea?

What is the difference between "Unknown" and "Installed" in magereport patch status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknown means that Magereport can't check if the patch is applied succesfully. You can check the patch logs to be certain that your patch is applied correctly. You can find the patch logs in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`

Log example:

```
 2016-11-02 11:59:47 UTC | SUPEE-7405 | CE_1.9.2.1 | v1.1 | 8175a2089e78fdc1141d444710ff4c0fafcf139f | Fri Feb 5 13:29:29 2016 +0200 | 856b2136f77eeb3f089ed77357f00b17ba143d32..8175a2089e78fdc1141d444710ff4c0fafcf139f
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

This means that the patch has been applied correctly.

Comment: In app/etc/applied.patches.list file having patch name . so no need to check in magereport? @Tjitse

Comment: @Nadh i've edited my answer.

Comment: yes it shows in my file but magereport not detecting ,it shows as "not installed"

Comment: @Nadh are you using Varnish or some other Full Page Cache module? It might be that something is cached.  Try to clear all of your caches.

Comment: iam not using that modules

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `app/etc/applied.patches.`list file

If this file has your patch name, it means, it is completely installed.

Clear cache, reindex and check again, if it is there and still coming not installed.

Comment: In applied patch list it shows it as patch file name but in magereport only not getting installed status@disha